# camelCase to snake_case in sed for ill formatted python code

Tags: python, regex, sed

I have some python code written in camelCase, but according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) variable names should be written in snake_case. I wrote a small sed script that managed to take any lowercase letter \1, followed by a upper case letter \2 and turn it into \1_ and a lowercase \2

```
find . -iname \*.py | xargs sed -i "s/\([a-z]\)\([A-Z]\)/\1_\L\2/g"
```

However this will turn *CamelCase* into Camel_case. According to the same [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) standard class names should be written in CamelCase starting with a capital letter.

How can I write a sed script that do not touch CamelCase but translates *camelCamelCamelCamel...* into *camel_camel_camel_camel...*?

I have a feeling that I am hitting a limit of regular expressions as I must keep the context of a word starting with a lower case letter for an unknown number of "camel humps". I know I can do this in another tool, but I wonder if sed can do this. An argument for this being impossible would also suffice.

I am using GNU sed 4.2.2

Comment: Should you decide it's not worth the effort: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/

Comment: Isn't it sad that whatever you wanna do, there is already a py package for that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's not clear that autopep8 even detects the N* errors. Can you cite a doc or some example code?

Comment: Update: autopep8 does NOT fix naming violations. It uses the pep8 module, which itself only detects these violations: https://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/1.6.2/intro.html#error-codes. The disclaimer (top of page) specifically states that naming conventions are not handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the comments mentions [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/), which probably is the way to go for OP, but it is instructive to attempt this in sed (by which I mean that it's a fun puzzle).

It is possible with this:

```
sed -r ':loop; /.*\<([a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+)\>.*/ { h; s//\1/; s/([A-Z])/_\l\1/g; G; s/(.*)\n(.*)\<[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+\>(.*)/\2\1\4/; b loop }'
```

The code is

```
:loop
/.*\<([a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+)\>.*/ {
  h
  s//\1/
  s/([A-Z])/_\l\1/g
  G
  s/(.*)\n(.*)\<[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+\>(.*)/\2\1\4/
  b loop
}
```

Here, `\<[a-z]+([A-Z][a-z]+)+\>` matches a dromedaryCase term. `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries, to ensure that this *only* matches such terms. So this does, in a loop:

1. if the line contains a dromedaryCase term:
2. save the whole line to the hold buffer
3. isolate the dromedaryCase term. This uses the fact that `//` reuses the last regex, which is the one from 1.
4. replace all upper case letters with `_` followed by their lower-case counterpart (this uses the GNU extension `\l`; otherwise you'd need a `y/ABCDEF.../abcdef.../` command to change the case). The pattern space now contains the the snake_case counterpart to the dromedaryCase term.
5. append the original line from the hold buffer to the pattern space
6. Building on the original regex, split the pattern space into the relevant parts: `\1` is the snake_case term, `\2` is the part of the original line before the replaced part, `\4` is the part after the dromedaryCaseTerm. Then reassemble these parts in the proper order.
7. loop until all dromedaryCase terms in the line are replaced.

Comment: Nice explanation to the most complicated sed expression I have seen. I did not even know looping was possible in sed. autopep8 seems like it is the way to go, but I got a bit curious on the limits of sed and regular expressions in general.

Comment: There's a proof that sed is turing-complete [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/proof-that-sed-is-turing-complete/). Less esoterically, GNU sed can call arbitrary shell commands, so...yes, powerful. But at some point you want to consider other options, and that point is well before this level of complexity is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = re.sub("([A-Z])", r"_\1", text, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```